# Sharing local web-server (Windows, NAT) in Internet

Tags: web, web-server, tunneling

There is a Windows machine connected to Internet by NAT (no IP, no incoming connections). Is there any way to make local web-server on this machine accessible from Internet by static IP or domain?

Web-server: Apache + MySQL + PHP

P.S. I found only one solution: using Opera Unit with Web Proxy application, but there are some problems with COOKIES.

Comment: What version of IIS?

Comment: No IIS, just Apache

Comment: Can you arrange for ports to be forwarded to your web server?

Comment: Discuss this with your system administrator.

Answer (score 1):

As long as your router is receiving a public IP address on the WAN side you will be able to do it by setting up port forwarding, which tells your router, for example, "port tcp/8000 goes to private IP A.B.C.D:tcp/80".

You will test it by the address http://A.B.C.D:8000/ from a PC in another place of the Internet, not the same as your LAN, to be sure.

However, your ISP may be giving you a "dynamic IP address" which means that it changes every N hours or so. Tough luck to keep it stable. You might want to try a dynamic DNS service like changeip.

Also, your ISP may be "protecting" its network with a firewall, which will not let you set ports up like this. (It will let you, it it won't work).

Just consider this will *NOT* give you a highly available service.